# Jstl: parse xml node content including child tags

Tags: xml, xpath, jstl, xslt-1.0

i'm working with JSTL but i'm still learning.

I have an xml like this one:

```
<doc>
    <header> my header </header>
    <text> 
        <p> first paragraph</p>
        <p> second paragraph</p>
        <author>my author</author>
        <p> third paragraph</p>
    </text>
</doc>
```

and i need to create from it the following html:

```
 <div class="text"> 
     <p> first paragraph</p>
     <p> second paragraph</p>
     <author>my author</author>
     <p> third paragraph</p>
 </div>
```

My code is the following:

```
<c:set var="xml_cont" value="${link.linkedObject.metadataAndContent}"/> //value is already valid xml

<x:set var="text" select="string($xml_cont//doc/text)"/>

<div class="text">${text}</div>
```

The problem is that this is wiping away all the child nodes of , is keeping the content but not the tag.

The html i get is:

```
 <div class="text"> 
      first paragraph
      second paragraph
      my author
      third paragraph
   </div>
```

How can i preserve sub nodes instead of turning all into pure text? I could not find anything in internet.

This is not the case but what if i would like to turn "author" sub node in something else: ex:

```
 <div class="author">
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
<x:set var="text" select="string($xml_cont//doc/text)"/>
```

the `string()` conversion removes all content of the `<text>` elements except for text content. See [string()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) and the string-value section of [Element Nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes).

I don't know jstl, so I can't really advise on how to fix this problem, but if I had to take a stab in the dark I'd try removing the `string()` function call and see if it gives an informative error message. Also, since you seem to want to copy only the children of `<text>` and not `<text>` itself, I would add `/*` on the end of your XPath expression:

```
<x:set var="text" select="$xml_cont//doc/text/*"/>
```